# PyGame: Viewport click & Drag

Tags: grid, pygame, drag, viewport

I'm trying to duplicate the behavior of some grid viewports (like *3ds Max*'s Orthometric view)
or map viewers like (*GoogleMaps*) where we have the map or grid, which is a whole lot bigger
than the screen, and we navigate by clicking somewhere in the viewport and dragging.

So far, i've managed to create a pretty big grid, draw it and make the viewport show only the tiles it should.

Here is my code so far:

```
import pygame, sys, math
from pygame.locals import *

FPS = 30
WINDOWWIDTH = 640
WINDOWHEIGHT = 480
GRIDWIDTH = 256
GRIDHEIGHT = 256
GRIDSIZE = 256
TILESIZE = 40
BGCOLOR = (128, 128, 128)
FGCOLOR = (64, 64, 64)

GRID = []

FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()

indexX = None
indexY = None

minVPcoordX = 0
minVPcoordY = 0
maxVPcoordX = (TILESIZE*GRIDSIZE)-WINDOWWIDTH
maxVPcoordY = (TILESIZE*GRIDSIZE)-WINDOWHEIGHT
viewportOffset = (0, 0)
vpStartXTile = 0
vpStartYTile = 0
viewportCoord = (0, 0)

coordX = 0
coordY = 0

movedDistanceX = 0
movedDistanceY = 0

speed = 4

def main():
    global FPSCLOCK, DISPLAYSURF
    global coordX, coordY
    global offsetX, offsetY, negativeOffsetX, negativeOffsetY
    global movedDistanceX, movedDistanceY

    DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))

    mouseX = 0
    mouseY = 0

    generateGrid(GRIDSIZE, GRIDSIZE)

    LeftButton = False
    mousePos = (0, 0)
    dragStart = (0,0)
    dragEnd = (0,0)

    pygame.font.init()
    arialFnt = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 16)
    while True:
        DISPLAYSURF.fill(BGCOLOR)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        #X
        if coordX < maxVPcoordX:
            coordX += speed
        elif coordX < minVPcoordX:
            coordX = 0
        else:
            coordX = maxVPcoordX
        #Y   
        if coordY < maxVPcoordY:
            coordY += speed
        elif coordY < minVPcoordY:
            coordY = 0
        else:
            coordY = maxVPcoordY
        #-------------

        viewportCoord = (coordX, coordY)
        print(coordX, coordY)

        vpStartXTile = math.floor(float(viewportCoord[0]/TILESIZE))
        vpStartYTile = math.floor(float(viewportCoord[1]/TILESIZE))
        GRIDstartTile = GRID[vpStartXTile][vpStartYTile]

        negativeOffsetX = viewportCoord[0] - GRID[vpStartXTile][vpStartYTile][0]
        negativeOffsetY = viewportCoord[1] - GRID[vpStartXTile][vpStartYTile][1]

        offsetX = TILESIZE - negativeOffsetX
        offsetY = TILESIZE - negativeOffsetY

        repeatX = math.floor(WINDOWWIDTH/TILESIZE)
        repeatY = math.floor(WINDOWHEIGHT/TILESIZE)

        drawGrid(repeatX, repeatY)

        outputLabel = arialFnt.render('(Top-Left)Coordinates: x%s - y%s' % (coordX, coordY), 1, (255,255,255))
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(outputLabel, (10, 10))

        # frame draw
        pygame.display.set_caption("Memory Game - FPS: %.0f" % FPSCLOCK.get_fps())
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.display.update()
        FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)



def generateGrid(xTiles=None, yTiles=None):
    global GRID

    GRID = []

    for i in range(xTiles):
        GRID.append([None] * yTiles)

    ix = 0
    iy = 0

    posX = -40

    for x in range(len(GRID[ix])):
        posX += TILESIZE
        posY = -40
        iy = 0
        for y in range(xTiles):
            posY += TILESIZE
            position = (posX, posY)
            GRID[ix][iy] = position
            iy += 1
        if ix < xTiles:
            ix += 1
        else:
            return

def drawGrid(x=None, y=None):
    lineWidth = 1

    xPos = 0
    yPos = 0

    for i in range(x):
        xStart = (xPos + offsetX, 0)
        xEnd = (xPos + offsetX, WINDOWHEIGHT + negativeOffsetY)
        pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF, FGCOLOR, xStart, xEnd, lineWidth)
        xPos += TILESIZE

    for i in range(y):
        yStart = (0, yPos + offsetY)
        yEnd = (WINDOWWIDTH + negativeOffsetX, yPos + offsetY)
        pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF, FGCOLOR, yStart, yEnd, lineWidth)
        yPos += TILESIZE

def moveGrid():    
    pass

def zoomIn():
    pass

def zoomOut():
    pass

main()
```

As you can see, it works as expected (i haven't implemented any form of click&drag
 in this sample).

It seems that *pygame* doesn't have an event for this, so it must be a combination of
**MOUSEBUTTONDOWN** and **MOUSEMOTION**.

I've tried storing the positions of the previous frame with the **get_pos()** and subtracting the current frame's positions, but i can't figure out the next. 
 It accelerates way too fast..
I've also tried this with the **get_rel()** method of the mouse, with no success.
(Though i'm pretty sure i wasn't supposed to ++ the mouse position to the screen position)

I researched around to see if anyone else did this but i found only how to drag around something
on a fixed screen. I need the opposite - drag the screen around on a fixed grid.

So, if anyone has any idea or advice on how to make this mechanic, or any link that i could study about it, i would be grateful!

ps: I found something similar but it's written in JS and it's a pain to translate)

Comment: Take a look at this demo. You can use the mouse to scroll the grid. http://code.google.com/p/ninmonkey/source/browse/#hg%2Fexamples%2Fmaptiles_numpy%253Fstate%253Dclosed

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot! I'll post the fixed code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working!

It still has some issues on the zoomIn/zoomOut additions but the main problem of dragging
the grid around is fixed.

```
import pygame, sys, math
from pygame.locals import *

FPS = 30
WINDOWWIDTH = 640
WINDOWHEIGHT = 480
GRIDSIZE = 256
TILESIZE = 40
BGCOLOR = (128, 128, 128)
FGCOLOR = (64, 64, 64)

GRID = []

FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()

indexX = None
indexY = None

minVPcoordX = 0
minVPcoordY = 0
maxVPcoordX = (TILESIZE*GRIDSIZE)-WINDOWWIDTH
maxVPcoordY = (TILESIZE*GRIDSIZE)-WINDOWHEIGHT
viewportOffset = (0, 0)
vpStartXTile = 0
vpStartYTile = 0
viewportCoord = (0, 0)

coordX = 0
coordY = 0

def main():
    global FPSCLOCK, DISPLAYSURF
    global coordX, coordY
    global offsetX, offsetY, negativeOffsetX, negativeOffsetY
    global movedDistanceX, movedDistanceY
    global isDragging

    DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))

    mouseX = 0
    mouseY = 0

    generateGrid(GRIDSIZE, GRIDSIZE)

    isDragging = False
    mousePos = (0, 0)
    dragStart = (0,0)
    dragEnd = (0,0)

    pygame.font.init()
    arialFnt = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 16)
    while True:
        DISPLAYSURF.fill(BGCOLOR)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 2:
                    isDragging = True
                elif event.button == 4:
                    zoomIn()
                elif event.button == 5:
                    zoomOut()
            elif event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
                mouseRel = pygame.mouse.get_rel()
                moveGrid(mouseRel)
            elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                isDragging = False

        viewportCoord = (coordX, coordY)

        vpStartXTile = math.floor(float(viewportCoord[0]/TILESIZE))
        vpStartYTile = math.floor(float(viewportCoord[1]/TILESIZE))
        GRIDstartTile = GRID[vpStartXTile][vpStartYTile]

        negativeOffsetX = viewportCoord[0] - GRID[vpStartXTile][vpStartYTile][0]
        negativeOffsetY = viewportCoord[1] - GRID[vpStartXTile][vpStartYTile][1]

        offsetX = TILESIZE - negativeOffsetX
        offsetY = TILESIZE - negativeOffsetY

        repeatX = math.floor(WINDOWWIDTH/TILESIZE)
        repeatY = math.floor(WINDOWHEIGHT/TILESIZE)

        drawGrid(repeatX, repeatY)

        outputLabel = arialFnt.render('(Top-Left)Coordinates: x%s - y%s' % (coordX, coordY), 1, (255,255,255))
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(outputLabel, (10, 10))

        # frame draw
        pygame.display.set_caption("Memory Game - FPS: %.0f" % FPSCLOCK.get_fps())
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.display.update()
        FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)



def generateGrid(xTiles=None, yTiles=None):
    global GRID

    GRID = []

    for i in range(xTiles):
        GRID.append([None] * yTiles)

    ix = 0
    iy = 0

    posX = -40

    for x in range(len(GRID[ix])):
        posX += TILESIZE
        posY = -40
        iy = 0
        for y in range(xTiles):
            posY += TILESIZE
            position = (posX, posY)
            GRID[ix][iy] = position
            iy += 1
        if ix < xTiles:
            ix += 1
        else:
            return

def drawGrid(x=None, y=None):
    lineWidth = 1

    xPos = 0
    yPos = 0

    for i in range(x):
        xStart = (xPos + offsetX, 0)
        xEnd = (xPos + offsetX, WINDOWHEIGHT + negativeOffsetY)
        pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF, FGCOLOR, xStart, xEnd, lineWidth)
        xPos += TILESIZE

    for i in range(y):
        yStart = (0, yPos + offsetY)
        yEnd = (WINDOWWIDTH + negativeOffsetX, yPos + offsetY)
        pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF, FGCOLOR, yStart, yEnd, lineWidth)
        yPos += TILESIZE

def moveGrid(rel):
    global coordX, coordY, isDragging


    if isDragging == True:
        #X
        if coordX <= maxVPcoordX and coordX >= minVPcoordX:
            coordX = coordX - rel[0]
            if coordX > maxVPcoordX:
                coordX = maxVPcoordX
            if coordX < minVPcoordX:
                coordX = 0
        #Y   
        if coordY <= maxVPcoordY and coordY >= minVPcoordY:
            coordY = coordY - rel[1]
            if coordY > maxVPcoordY:
                coordY = maxVPcoordY
            elif coordY < minVPcoordY:
                coordY = 0
    #-------------



def zoomIn():
    global TILESIZE, maxVPcoordX, maxVPcoordY

    TILESIZE += 4

    print("Tile size: ", TILESIZE)

    generateGrid(GRIDSIZE, GRIDSIZE)

    maxVPcoordX = (TILESIZE*GRIDSIZE)-WINDOWWIDTH
    maxVPcoordY = (TILESIZE*GRIDSIZE)-WINDOWHEIGHT


def zoomOut():
    global TILESIZE, maxVPcoordX, maxVPcoordY

    TILESIZE -= 4
    if TILESIZE <= 0:
        TILESIZE = 4

    print("Tile size: ", TILESIZE)

    generateGrid(GRIDSIZE, GRIDSIZE)

    maxVPcoordX = (TILESIZE*GRIDSIZE)-WINDOWWIDTH
    maxVPcoordY = (TILESIZE*GRIDSIZE)-WINDOWHEIGHT

main()
```

Comment: Remember that you may accept your own answers so that people viewing this question in the future with the same problem will see that this is how the problem was solved.

Comment: For future visitors, here is the diff between the code (since the post doesn't actually mention what changed and what the solution was): https://www.diffchecker.com/QzypNclW